# Access to a private blockchain controlled by one entity

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, private-key

How can I be the unique authority that can grant access to my private blockchain to only my users and forbid that users to grant access to others?

Answer (score 1):

To connect to a blockchain you need only

1. the genesis block
2. known peers (or a bootnode)

I don't know of the possibility to limit connectivity to peers that you explicitly allow. Maybe you could limit the access to the nodes themselves through network measures.

Also, being the unique authority on a blockchain defeats it's intention of being "trustless".

Comment: Yes, I agree, but this is what should make it private in term of access.

Comment: Then I would suggest implementing your nodes in a (virtual) private network as my best bet.

Comment: the problem is not in the implementation, but how to grant access to only authorized node.